# How to create a DataFrame in Spark from a variable dimensional data

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset with variable dimension as follows:

```
sample_id   ctype   total_ids   gene_ids
1             1       3637      [2, 3, 9, 10, 11, 14, 16, 17]
2             2       3500      [1, 3, 9, 10, 11, 14, 16, 17, 20, 35]
3             3       3737      [2, 3, 9, 10, 11, 14]
```

How could I create a Spark DataFrame for machine learning model? Here ctype is the label and others can be considered as features. My current code is as follows:

```
val train = spark.read.
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("delimiter", "\t")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load("data/file.csv")
```

It creates a sample dataframe in the following format:

```
+---------+-----+---------+--------------------+
|sample_id|ctype|total_ids|            gene_ids|
+---------+-----+---------+--------------------+
|        1|    1|     3637|[2, 3, 9, 10, 11,...|
|        2|    1|      361|[1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8...|
|        3|    1|     5358|[1, 2, 3, 9, 11, ...|
+---------+-----+---------+--------------------+
```

But it should be something like below (this is just an example) so that it can be feed into a ML model -e.g. RandomForest:

```
+-----+--------------------+
|label|            features|
+-----+--------------------+
|  1.0|(20,[1,2,3,4,6,7,...|
|  2.0|(40,[1,2,4,6,7,8,...|
|  3.0|(50,[1,2,3,5,6,9,...|
+-----+--------------------+
```

Comment: where do 20,40,50 come from? And are the values on the rhs of the tuple the gene_ids?

Comment: Hi, this is just an example (so of course could be different in practice), I have updated my question. Yes, the RHS of the tuple is the gene ids.

Comment: What's the lhs of the tuple meant to represent?

Comment: You're welcome to relocate the columns or don't use  the CSV parser and define your own schema over an RDD to a Dataset. However, as stated, it's not clear where those values are coming from

Comment: These are actually CNV (copy number variations). For example, in row 1, there are 8 genes associated. On the other hand, 10 and 6 genes are in row 2 and 3 respectively. I was planning to add padding -e.g. 0 so that the shape of the data frame would be the same. But don't know how to do it.